# Do i need to start and resume the OntouchListener?

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have attached the `OnTouchListener` with `ImageView` control, now my question is do i need to start and resume the `listener` (if possible) to save the resources, like we do in the case of other sensor devices like `accelerelometer`, `compass` etc? Or in case of Touch it wont require and it will not put any effect on battery etc.

Comment: Your title should be "Do I need to register and unregister the OnTouchListener"

Answer (score 1):

well if you let the listener attached to the imageview or not doesn't effect on the cpu or battery life. I mean of course have effect but that is not something that you should care, it is not like listeners of compas . . .

// you can do this
button1.setOnTouchListener(null);

but I told you there is no need to unregister onTouch listeners.

If you are concerned for memory usage or cpu usage you should pay attention on other things. unregistering touch listener will not help to you application to be better or faster